# Files loaded from server in Dropzone are shown in the queue

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I've followed [this FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server) and various other SO questions regarding showing files in dropzone that are already on the server.

I'm having trouble showing the files in their "completed" state, ie hide start/cancel upload buttons, show delete button.

According to the FAQ, this line should take care of it:

```
// Make sure that there is no progress bar, etc...
myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
```

Unfortunately, the files are still showing as if they have just been added to the upload queue.

[image: Files from server shown in upload queue]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
    url: "/upload/", // Set the url
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    init: function () {
        var myDropzone = this;

        var thumbnailUrls = [
            {name: 'myimage1.jpg', size: 312, type: 'image/jpeg', url: 'skdfjlk'},
            {name: 'another2.png', size: 0928, type: 'image/png', url: 'aeserre'}
        ];

        //Populate any existing thumbnails
        if (thumbnailUrls) {
            for (var i = 0; i < thumbnailUrls.length; i++) {
                var mockFile = {
                    name: thumbnailUrls[i].name,
                    size: thumbnailUrls[i].size,
                    type: thumbnailUrls[i].type,
                    status: Dropzone.ADDED,
                    url: thumbnailUrls[i].url
                };

                // Call the default addedfile event handler
                myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

                // And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
                myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, thumbnailUrls[i]);

                myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);

                myDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of dropzone are you using? v4.0?

Comment: I downloaded it last week. So 4.0.0 I believe.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is still visible and shouldn't be? A screenshot would be ideal.

Comment: @enyo I've added a screenshot into my question. Basically the Start and Cancel upload buttons are showing, where I would have expected to see delete buttons

Comment: Ah Ok, so you used the bootstrap theming example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the bootstrap configuration that you are using, only hides the Start and Cancel button on success.
You have to ways to approach this:

1. Change the CSS to hide/show the appropriate buttons depending on the `.dz-complete` instead of the `.dz-success` class (Code below)
2. Emit a `success` event in addition to the `complete` event (you can try this, by simply executing this in your browser: `myDropzone.emit('success', myDropzone.files[0]);`

This would be the updated CSS:

```
/* Hide the start and cancel buttons and show the delete button */
#previews .file-row.dz-complete .start,
#previews .file-row.dz-complete .cancel {
  display: none;
}
#previews .file-row.dz-complete .delete {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you! Adding the success event worked perfectly